# How to move max count value of a field to another in DE using a Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, oracle

1. I have created a table in Data Extension that contains 4 fields. All fields are Nullable. One field Name is Checked. In that field the values are Yes and No according to the requirement. Now I want Max count of either YES or NO and that need to be saved in another table in a new column.
2. Can anyone help me in building this query.

Currently using:

```
Select Check, CASE
                  COUNT(distinct Winner)
                  WHEN Yes THEN 'Yes'
                  ELSE 'No'
              END as winner
FROM Test_Table
```

I changed my Query this way:

```
select max(Final) as Winner from (
                Select distinct Seafood, max(Seafood) as Final
                 from Tirumala_Testing_New
                  group by Seafood
                         ) A
```

This is not printing the max value it is just taking the random value
how to display max value

Comment: Select Check,

case count(distinct Winner)

when Yes then 'Yes'

else 'No'

end as winner

from Test_Table(I tried this) But it is not working

Comment: Please be more specific than *it is not working*.

Comment: Am getting syntax error near the variable name Check

Comment: You aren't using the case function properly

Comment: Count distinct winner is an agregate function and cannot return a string "yes"

Comment: Can you please share a sample code.  How to use Case function to find a Max count value of one column  @Data_Kid

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 


Max(Winner) as Winner


FROM 

(CASE WHEN Checked IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END as Winner FROM Tirumala_Testing_New UNION
CASE WHEN Column1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END as Winner FROM Tirumala_Testing_New UNION
CASE WHEN Column2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END as Winner FROM Tirumala_Testing_New UNION
CASE WHEN Column3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END as Winner FROM Tirumala_Testing_New) x
```